# Reading smartcard from chrome after NPAPI drop

Tags: google-chrome, smartcard, npapi

[This chromium blog](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/11/the-final-countdown-for-npapi.html) states Chrome is dropping NPAPI for good now.

In my current project I need to access a [Belgian E-ID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_identity_card) card to get data (not authentication).
All documentation and examples I found are using Java plugins. This will become imposible in the future.

Does anybody have an idea how to approach this?

Answer (score 2):

[Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging) is probably what you'll need to use.  The FireBreath team is working on some possibilities for extending support to allow using it, but nothing we can definitively announce yet.

Comment: This would require us to roll our own native service first. It's a solution, but I hope something better will become available. Will be following the discussion at the Firebreath site.

Comment: Also, native messaging is Chrome only.

Comment: Yes, Native messaging is Chrome only.  There are no potential technologies on the horizon that work on all browsers, though NPAPI is so far only being dropped from Chrome.

Comment: Brief update: the firefox team has stated on mailing lists that they plan to support native messaging as well sometime before they drop plugin support at the end of 2016